# How to get wordpress post image link to display on android application

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-layout, wordpress-rest-api

I am learning android application and view lots of youtube tutorial to implement wordpress post into android application and found some steps and resources.

I have follow below steps:

1. get blog post using REST APi..it will be a JSON array.
2. check each json object, each have this JSON object- Links --> WpFeaturedmedia--->object(0)-->Href
3. this Href is index of image for the blog post.
4. pass this href to adapter..
5. inside adapter class again use another retrofit call for this href url
6. the response of this retrofit will have all images(multiple sizes) of blog post. response.body().getMediaDetails().getSizes().getThumbnail().getSourceUrl()
7. pass it to glide method (inside adpater class only) Glide.with(mContext) .load( response.body().getMediaDetails().getSizes().getThumbnail().getSourceUrl()) .into(imageView);
8. Create another POJO for image url.

but, I am stuck on **getImageRetrofit**. while checking the catlog show image is retrieving the image link but could not pass the image link. can some one please guide me or help me to fetch image link or complete the below codes.

```
package np.com.wp_restapi;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;

import com.bumptech.glide.Glide;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import okhttp3.OkHttpClient;
import okhttp3.logging.HttpLoggingInterceptor;
import retrofit2.Call;
import retrofit2.Callback;
import retrofit2.Response;
import retrofit2.Retrofit;
import retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonConverterFactory;

public class NewsNotice1_Activity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private ProgressBar progressBar;
    private LinearLayoutManager mLayoutManager;
    private ArrayList<Model> list;
    private RecyclerViewAdapter adapter;

    private String baseURL = "http:////example.com/";

    public static List<WPPost> mListPost;
    private static Retrofit retrofit = null;
    private static String ImageHref=null;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.news_notice_1);

        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
        progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressbar);

        mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(NewsNotice1_Activity.this, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);

        list = new ArrayList<Model>();

        progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        if (mListPost != null) {
            /// call retrofill
            getRetrofit();
        } else {

            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

        adapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(list, NewsNotice1_Activity.this);

        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    public void getRetrofit() {
        Log.d(TAG, "i am inside_200");

        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(baseURL)
                .client(okHttpClient)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();

        RetrofitArrayApi service = retrofit.create(RetrofitArrayApi.class);
        Call<List<WPPost>> call = service.getPostInfo();

        call.enqueue(new Callback<List<WPPost>>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<List<WPPost>> call, Response<List<WPPost>> response) {
                try {
                    Log.e("NewsNotice_Activity", " response123 " + response.body());
                    mListPost = response.body();
                    progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                    for (int i = 0; i < response.body().size(); i++) {
                        String tempImageHref = response.body().get(i).getFeaturedMedia().toString();
                        Log.e("Href", "onResponse: " + tempImageHref);

                        getImageRetrofit(tempImageHref, ImageHref);

                        Log.e("main ", " title " + response.body().get(i).getTitle().getRendered() + " " +
                                response.body().get(i).getId());

                        String tempdetails = response.body().get(i).getExcerpt().getRendered().toString();

                        String tempDate = response.body().get(i).getDate();
                        tempDate = tempDate.replace("T", " ");

                        tempdetails = tempdetails.replace("<p>", "");
                        tempdetails = tempdetails.replace("</p>", "");
                        tempdetails = tempdetails.replace("[&hellip;]", "");


                        list.add(new Model(Model.IMAGE_TYPE, tempDate, response.body().get(i).getTitle().getRendered(),
                                tempdetails, ImageHref
                                
                        )); 
                    }

                } finally {
                    System.out.println("finally");

                }
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<List<WPPost>> call, Throwable t) {
                t.printStackTrace();
            }
        });
    }
    public interface RevealCourtPlaceCallbacks {
        void onSuccess(@NonNull String value);

        void onError(@NonNull Throwable throwable);
    }
//, @Nullable final RevealCourtPlaceCallbacks callbacks



    private void getImageRetrofit(final String tempImageHref, final String ImageHref) {
        Log.e("getImageRetrofit", "called " + tempImageHref);

           retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                   .baseUrl(baseURL)
                   .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                   .build();
   

        RetrofitArrayApi service1 = retrofit.create(RetrofitArrayApi.class);
        Call<WPPostImage> callImage = service1.getImageInfo(tempImageHref);

        callImage.enqueue(new Callback<WPPostImage>() {


            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<WPPostImage> call, Response<WPPostImage> response) {
               Log.e("ImageInfo1","info1: "+response.body().getMediaDetails().getSizes().getThumbnail().getSourceUrl());
               
              
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<WPPostImage> call, Throwable t) {
                //Log.e("Link Failed: ",": t.printStackTrace()" );
                Log.e("Link Failed: ", t.getMessage());
                t.printStackTrace();
            }


        });
        return;
    }

    public static List<WPPost> getList() {
        return mListPost;
    }

}
```